# Spreadsheet: Issue with merge()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, i get some issue with the merge() function:
I script a function that create spreadsheet/sheet and arrange them, and all it OK with that.
But when i want to merge some cells for sheet, I get an error saying that "can't merge the selected cells" [not the actually english error msg, but equivalent].

See the code:

```
function style(id,magasin,Nom,dateTest){
var ssMois = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
var sheet = ssMois.getSheetByName(Nom);

var date=dateTest.toLocaleDateString();

sheet.getRange("A1:D1").merge();
sheet.getRange("B1").setValue("Feuille de caisse du:");

sheet.getRange("C1:E1").mergeAcross();
sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(date);

sheet.getRange("B2:F2").merge();
sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(magasin);

//BLOC RECETTE DU JOUR ******

sheet.getRange("B4:F4").merge();
sheet.getRange("B4").setValue("RECETTE DU JOUR");

sheet.getRange("C5").setValue("Caisse 1");
sheet.getRange("D5").setValue("Caisse 2");
sheet.getRange("E5").setValue("Total");
    sheet.getRange("E7:E10").setFormulas("=R[0]C[-2]+R[0]C[-1]")

sheet.getRange("B6").setValue("CAISSIER");
sheet.getRange("B7").setValue("ESPECE DU JOUR");
sheet.getRange("B8").setValue("CARTE BLEU");
sheet.getRange("B9").setValue("CHEQUE");
sheet.getRange("B10").setValue("TOTAL (€)");


//BLOC FOND DE CAISSE ******
sheet.getRange("B12:F12").merge();
sheet.getRange("B12").setValue("DETERMINATION DU FOND DE CAISSE");

sheet.getRange("B13").setValue("Fond de caisse J-1");
sheet.getRange("B14").setValue("SOUS-TOTAL");
sheet.getRange("B15").setValue("PRELEVEMENT");
sheet.getRange("B16").setValue("SORTIE DE CAISSE");
sheet.getRange("B17").setValue("Fond de caisse théorique:");
sheet.getRange("B18").setValue("Fond de caisse compté:");
sheet.getRange("B19").setValue("Erreur");

//BLOC SORTIE DE CAISSE ******

}
```

The strange fact come here:

if I put the first merge `sheet.getRange("A1:D1").merge();` in comment, the code is ok.
if I change the range "A1:D1" for anything else, *sometime*, the code will work.
If i put the full code in comment, except the first three lines, will work.
Of course, I can merge this manually with the merge button.

Doesn't understand this error, may u help me seeing a correction, or a workaround ?

Comment: Can you merge this range manually? You may have a filter or other feature that is preventing the merge. By trying to do manually you may get a better error message.

Comment: Yes, i can merge it manually.</br>

I find my error (my stupid error) here:
`sheet.getRange("A1:D1").merge();
sheet.getRange("B1").setValue("Feuille de caisse du:");
sheet.getRange("C1:E1").mergeAcross();
sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(date);`

I merge the A1:D1, then the C1:E1 but the C1 and D1 are already merge!

SO the issue is resolved. Maybe the error msg can be more userfriendly but totally my fault, thx anyway

Comment: you should [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a fail in my code:
I firstly merge the A1:D1, then the C1:E1 collumn.

So, the script can't merge C1:E1 since the C1 cell is already merge with the A1.

The only complain i can make is that the error msg can be more specific: no cell or line are show; just a generic msg "cell can't be merge"